# Why is range protection taking so long

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am needing to range protect cells on a sheet based on the name in the cell. I can obtain a persons email address from their name and protect the cell so only they can edit it.

It seems to be taking a very long time to add a person to the range protection. I have used the logger to find out what is taking so long and it appears protection.addEditor() is taking 27700ms and protection.removeEditors() is taking 21904ms. Is this normal?

The workbook is shared with a set group of about 30 people, there are about 60 sheets and the workbook contains about 300,000 cells in total.

Any ideas why this is taking so long?

I am getting an **Error: Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id ....** This does not happen every time the script is run, but when it does it always happens at the point where I am protecting a cell. I run an overnight process to look for new entries and protect those cells so only the named person can edit. It is used as a shift booking system.

I was hoping it might be possible to protect all the cells that need protecting  in one go for each sheet, but I cannot find anything about how to do this.

```
  function protectActiveCell() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var bookCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var name = bookCell.getValue();
  var person = getPersonFromName(name);
  var email = person.email;
  *emphasized text*var others = getOtherUsersEmails(email);
  
  removeCellProtection(bookCell);

  var protection = bookCell.protect();
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  protection.addEditor(email);

  protection.removeEditors(others);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
}
  
  function removeCellProtection(cell) {
  
  // Remove range protections from specific cell.
  
  var sheet = cell.getSheet();

  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {

    var protection = protections[i];

    if (protection.getRange().getA1Notation() == cell.getA1Notation()) {

      protection.remove();

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you effectively have 300k protected ranges that you scan through every time?

Comment: Every evening about 250,000 cells effectively get scanned through by bringing back a table of cells with entries in. This will result in only 5000 cells. If the protection matches the name nothing happens.